# String remove from last

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have

```
string query="Date >= '" + FromDate + "' AND Date <= '" + ToDate + "' OR ";
```

I want to remove **OR** from this string coming at last.
How I Can remove this from string.

Comment: I am getting query at run time , and at last this will have to remove .

Answer (score 3):

```
query = query.Substring(0, query.LastIndexOf("OR"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
query = query.Substring(0, query.LastIndexOf("OR"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you:

1. Use string formatting instead of string concatenations
2. Not to add string which you need to remove

I.e.

```
var query = String.Format("Date >= '{0}' AND Date <= '{1}'", FromDate, ToDate);
```

BTW If you are building SQL query this way, then consider to use query parameters instead:

```
var query = "Date >= @fromDate AND Date <= @toDate";
```

Answer (score 1):

try replace last occurence:

```
query = query.Substring(0, query.LastIndexOf("OR"));
```

or remove:

```
query= query.Remove(str.LastIndexOf("OR"), 2);
```

Comment: If the query will be like this {
string query="Date >= '" + FromDate + "' AND Date <= '" + ToDate + "' OR Date <= '" + ToDate + "' OR ";
} then it will replace all OR from Query i want to remove only from last.

Comment: I didn't downvote yet, but your original solution was wrong and you copy-pasted correct solution. I suggest you to remove this answer, thus same answer(s) already was provided

Comment: Your last solution makes sence, but if it will be posted as separate answer, without incorrect upvotes of your original solution

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy it has additional way which no other answer included. and thanks for no downvote :)

Comment: @ZaheerAhmed that's my way - I always explain what's wrong with answer  instead of downvoting :)